# Trouble with the default view undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, show

I'm having trouble getting my view to render. I think I know why I'm getting the error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #21): (showing 18-24)

```
<ul>
     <%= form_tag(default_hero_user_path, :method=>'post') do %>
         <%= label_tag "Name" %>
         <%= text_field_tag "name", @user.default_hero.name %> #line 21
         <%= submit_tag 'Set hero', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"  %>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
```

I know you can't call .name on a nil object but I don't understand why @user.default_hero is nil. I want the user to be able to set their 'hero' but having trouble setting the default obviously.

Here is the users controller:

```
# creates or updates the default hero
def default_hero
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 hero = @user.default_hero
 if hero.nil?
   # we don't have a default hero so we need to add one'
   hero = Hero.new
   @user.heros << hero
 end
 hero.default = true
 hero.name = params[:name]
 hero.save
 redirect_to @user # shows the user again to see any updates
end
```

And here is where I believe I am having the problem in setting a default view-

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id]) 
if @user.default_hero.nil?
  name = params[:q]
else
  name = @user.default_hero.name
end
```

Thanks for your guys' time and attention if you can point me in the right direction in how to solve this I would ppreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `show` controller action doesn't make much sense. You are setting a local variable (which won't be accessible in the view) if `@user.default_hero.nil?`. This doesn't accomplish anything and `@user.default_hero` will still be `nil` in the view.

That being said, to get rid of your error you can simply do this:

```
<%= text_field_tag "name", @user.default_hero.nil? ? '' : @user.default_hero.name %>
```

---

Based on your comment I would does something like this:

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :heros

  def set_default_hero(name)
    hero = self.heros.find_by_name(name) # check if the hero exists already
    hero = self.heros.build(:name => name) if hero.nil? # new object if not
    hero.default = true # set it as default
    hero.save
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def default_hero
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.set_default_hero(params[:name])
  redirect_to @user
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @default_hero = @user.default_hero.nil? ? '' : @user.default_hero.name
end
```

View:

```
<%= text_field_tag "name", @default_hero %>
```

You ignored my question about `params[:q]`, so I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I need to go back to the MVC drawing board. Obviously, I don't want to just patch bad code, do you have a rec on any resources I can look up to help me understand my issue?

Comment: Hm, I don't know any resources of the top of my head. I could explain how I would do it, but I am not quite sure what you are trying to do. E.g. what is `params[:q]`? What do you want to do with the `name` variable? Please try to explain what you are trying to do in `show` and I can probably show you a better way. The `default_hero` method is a bit long. It would probably be better to move that code to a `set_default_hero` instance method in your `User` model.

Comment: I am trying to allow users to set their own 'hero' news feed. This would entail querying an API (http://www.guardian.co.uk/open-platform/content-api-content-search-reference-guide) with a name of their 'hero' e.g. john terry. But I guess I'm having trouble handling the case where the case where a hero hasn't been set. Does that help?

Comment: @mishca Thanks for your attention I understand the problem much better and I know what I need to focus on learning just a bit better. params[:q] was meant for users to query the guardian api with the name of their hero to return their content from the guardian.co.uk

Comment: Ah, I see, so you can try adding the code for querying the API somewhere yourself. I hope this gives you a basic idea of organizing things.